# get source code of a web page(html) with lua scripts

Tags: sockets, web, lua

How to get the source code of a web page (html) via Lua scripts and its library like 'socket.http'?
I want to extract a part of the code in the source code of a web page.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [LuaSocket manual](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html).

This will fetch the "source code" of the page you're reading right now:

```
 local http = require 'socket.http'
 local res, code, headers, status = 
        http.request 'http://stackoverflow.com/q/32907568/501459'
 print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.